How to allow the user to input more than one number of a specific item that is included in a dictionary
In an intro to comp sci course so this is very basic code and should remain so. I was tasked with creating a vending machine with various features and two of them that i am stuck on are allowing the user to enter more than one of an item in the vending machine i.e: user inputs that they want 2 lipsticks instead of 1. The second issue is creating code that will calculate the total of the cart while also accounting for how many of a specific item they got such as totalling their cart to $18 if they got 2 lipsticks and 1 eyeshadow instead of $10 (i hope that makes sense).  My code works so far and I haven't finished inputting the menu but I feel like I need to fix the two problems before I continue to creating my next else statement for option d (checkout)

makeup_cart = []

makeup = {'lipstick': 8.00, 'highlight': 9.00, 'eyeshadow': 2.00, 'foundation':11.00, 'eyeliner':5.00, 'bronzer':7.00, 'lipliner':7.00,'blush':5.00, 'mascara':8.00, 'lipgloss  ': 4.00 }

while True:
        print("\nMenu:")
        print("a = Display makeup list and prices")
        print("b = Add a makeup item to cart")
        print("c = View cart")
        print("d = Checkout")
        print("e = Exit")

        choice = input("Enter your choice (a-e): ")

        if choice == "a":
            print(makeup) # prints makeup dictionary
        elif choice == "b":
            item = input("Enter a makeup from the menu item to add: ") #prompts user to input for makeup to add to cart 
            makeup_cart.append(item) #adds item to cart
            print(f"your {item} has been added to the cart  ") 
            print (makeup_cart) # prints current cart
        elif choice == "c":
            if makeup_cart:
              print("Makeup Cart:")
              for item in makeup_cart: #prints items the user added into the cart as a list of items 
                print( item)
        else:
          print("The makeup cart is empty") # if user hasnt added anything then the cart will come up empty 
      

I was thinking to create another dictionary and use count+=1 so that the program takes into account the number of products the user wants. my next step is to create another else statement for option d which is checkout and thats where the second issue arises about how to calculate the total.

for counting the number of items the user wants you can just use:
    len(makeup)

for calculating the total price:
    elif choice=="c":
         sum=0
         for k,v in makeup.items():
             sum+=v
             print(sum)

k and v are assigned as key and value automatically during for statement,
this will give the total price while checking out.
also one more suggestion, use choice.lower() in your elif statements to make it slightly more versatile
